# DevOps reporting across all projects

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, reporting, project-management

Just to throw this into the pond, what's the best way to get some reporting visibility for DevOps's workitems across all projects in a single view.

i.e.

```
Resource: John Smith
Date from: dd/mm/yyyy to: dd/mm/yyyy

Project | Type         | Name  | Etc.
-------------------------------------
Prj1    |  Epic        |  XXXX | XXXX 
Prj1    |  Feature     |  XXXX | XXXX 
Prj1    |  User Story  |  XXXX | XXXX 
Prj1    |  Task        |  XXXX | XXXX 
Prj1    |  Task        |  XXXX | XXXX 
Prj2    |  Feature     |  XXXX | XXXX 
Prj2    |  User Story  |  XXXX | XXXX 
Prj2    |  User Story  |  XXXX | XXXX 
Prj2    |  Task        |  XXXX | XXXX
```

What's the best way to pull this kind of reporting setup into PowerBI.
I find the default connector is just not sufficient enough, perhaps there is a better way to pull an OData query out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this issue, you can create a query directly in `Queries`,check `Query across projects` option and customize the columns that need to be displayed through the `Column options` button.

[image]

If you want to integrate with Power Bi, there are currently two methods available: [Analytics view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/data-connector-connect?view=azure-devops) and [OData queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/powerbi/odataquery-connect?view=azure-devops).

Analytic view : you need to add all your projects in `Teams` and customize the columns that need to be displayed in `Fields`.

[image]

[image]

You can refer to this [guide](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/power-bi-and-vsts-integration-made-easy/) for details.

OData queries : In this way ,you need to construct organization-scoped queries to return work items of interest . You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/extend-analytics/account-scoped-queries?view=azure-devops) for samples.

Comment: Thanks.. I think OData queries may be the way to go here coz the queries can be more granular. What's the best approach for the queries, Is it recommended to query directly to DevOps on demand? or Is it worth pulling the data on scheduled basis and keep them in a DB somewhere?